# BindingSource entre mais de uma classe

Tags: c#

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C# windows form onde eu possuo minhas classes desenvolvidas de acordo com meu banco de dados.
Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer meu BindingSource listar em um DataGridView os dados da consulta.
Segue o método que preenche o BindingSource:

```
public List<Classes.clUsuarioSistema> ConsultaListaUsuario(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                clConexao.AbreConexao();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM USUARIOSISTEMA WHERE IDUSUARIO = @idusuario");
                cmd.Connection = clConexao.sqlConn;

                MySqlParameter parametroidUsuario = new MySqlParameter("@idusuario", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                parametroidUsuario.Value = id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parametroidUsuario);

                List<Classes.clUsuarioSistema> listaUsuarioSistema = new List<Classes.clUsuarioSistema>();

                MySqlDataReader drUsuarioSistema = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (drUsuarioSistema.Read())
                {
                    Classes.clUsuarioSistema vUsuarioSistema = new Classes.clUsuarioSistema();
                    Classes.clUsuario vUsuario = new Classes.clUsuario();
                    Classes.clSistema vSistema = new Classes.clSistema();
                    clSistemaDAO vSistemaDAO = new clSistemaDAO();
                    clUsuarioDAO vUsuarioDAO = new clUsuarioDAO();

                    vUsuario.idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(drUsuarioSistema["IDRESPONSAVEL"].ToString());
                    vUsuario.Login = vUsuarioDAO.Consultar(vUsuario.idUsuario).Login;

                    vSistema.idSistema = Convert.ToInt32(drUsuarioSistema["IDSISTEMA"].ToString());
                    vSistema.Descricao = vSistemaDAO.Consultar(vSistema.idSistema).Descricao;

                    vUsuarioSistema.DataAtualizacao = Convert.ToDateTime(drUsuarioSistema["DATAATUALIZACAO"].ToString());
                    vUsuarioSistema.Responsavel = vUsuario;
                    vUsuarioSistema.Sistema = vSistema;

                    listaUsuarioSistema.Add(vUsuarioSistema);
                }
                return listaUsuarioSistema.ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                clConexao.FechaConexao();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                clConexao.FechaConexao();
            }
        }
```

Onde esse retorno eu vinculo ao BindingSource do form.

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso fazer para que apareça na Grid os dados que eu preciso?

Comment: E como você está passando esses dados pra grid?

Comment: Josias, tente fazer um override do `toString` das classes `clUsuario` e `clSistema` para que retornem `Login` e `Descricao` respectivamente.

Comment: Na verdade eu sou iniciante no C#, peguei um projeto abandonado do meu pai e tava dando continuidade. De repente o override seja a solução, mas vou ter que dar uma lida no assunto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é a forma mais correta de se resolver esse problema, mas a solução que encontrei foi fazer um override, conforme aconselhado pelo TobyMosque. Agradeço a colaboração de todos.

Answer (score 2):

Você está passando o **objeto** e não a **propriedade**.

```
vUsuarioSistema.Responsavel = vUsuario;
vUsuarioSistema.Sistema = vSistema;
```

Nesse caso (eu não conheço sua classe), você deveria atribuir assim:

```
vUsuarioSistema.Responsavel = vUsuario.Nome;
vUsuarioSistema.Sistema = vSistema.Nome;
```

No caso o `Nome` é a propriedade que você deseja exibir.

Como citado pelo Jeférson, o FechaConexao no catch não é necessário, pois o **finally** sempre será executado independente se ocorreu um erro ou não.

Comment: seria interessante adicionar na tua resposta que aquele `FechaConexao` dentro do `catch` é desnecessário.

Comment: Agradeço muito o retorno de vocês. Porém da forma descrita pelo Laerte não dá, o sistema está esperando uma classe e eu tento passar uma string. Aparece o seguinte erro:Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Richter.Classes.clUsuario'

Comment: Como você está populando essa grid? Você só quer exibir um nome na grid? Por que não cria somente a propriedade ao invés de passar a classe inteira?

Comment: Pra popular a grid, eu vinculei o resultado do método descrito a um BindingSource que por sua vez eu vinculei a um bindingNavigator, então vinculei à grid.. Eu até consegui listar os dados que eu quero, mas fui adicionando cada coluna e seus respectivos dados, porém o bindingNavigator não fica vinculado a grid.